# error of listing all files/objects matching a given pattern on google cloud storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

i would like to list all files/objects (matching a given pattern) located in a folder on google cloud storage bucket from Jupyter notebook.

I am using the example at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix

```
 from google.cloud import storage

def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter=None):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket that begin with the prefix.

    This can be used to list all blobs in a "folder", e.g. "public/".

    The delimiter argument can be used to restrict the results to only the
    "files" in the given "folder". Without the delimiter, the entire tree under
    the prefix is returned. For example, given these blobs:

        a/1.txt
        a/b/2.txt

    If you specify prefix ='a/', without a delimiter, you'll get back:

        a/1.txt
        a/b/2.txt

    However, if you specify prefix='a/' and delimiter='/', you'll get back
    only the file directly under 'a/':

        a/1.txt

    As part of the response, you'll also get back a blobs.prefixes entity
    that lists the "subfolders" under `a/`:

        a/b/
    """

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)

    # Note: The call returns a response only when the iterator is consumed.
    print("Blobs:")
    for blob in blobs: # error 
        print(blob.name)

    if delimiter:
        print("Prefixes:")
        for prefix in blobs.prefixes:
            print(prefix)
 bucket_name = MY_GCS_BUCKET
 prefix = 'MY_FILES_*.model'
 list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix)
```

In MY_GCS_BUCKET, there are some files with pattern:

```
 MY_FILES_0.model
 MY_FILES_1.model
 MY_FILES_x.model # x can be 50
```

How to specify the pattern so that they can be listed ? thanks

Comment: Can you share the error you are facing by updating question?

Comment: You can only filter by prefix `/path/to/MY_FILES_*` no more

Comment: Try `**MY_FILES*.model`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match_glob` parameter, with something like: `**.model`.

For reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#list-objects-and-prefixes-using-glob